# Cannot update a field in a wire method

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have used a wire method here and I am obtaining the data in the  console in the data variable.But I have to enter it to a grant object's related fields.I tried assigning it in the wire but it isn't successful.Should I add an update record method separately.

```javascript
 import { LightningElement,api,wire, track} from 'lwc';
 import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
 import  Date_of_Visit__c from '@salesforce/schema/Site_Visit__c.Date_of_Visit__c';
 import Flags__c from '@salesforce/schema/Site_Visit__c.Flags__c';
 import Details__c from '@salesforce/schema/Site_Visit__c.Details__c';
 import GrantName from '@salesforce/schema/Site_Visit__c.Grant__c';
 import getSingleSitevisit from '@salesforce/apex/Sitevisit.getSingleSitevisit';
 export default class Lwcdata extends LightningElement {
     @api recordId;
     @api objectApiName;
     @api recordtypeId;
     @track data;
     @track error;
     date=Date_of_Visit__c;
     details=Details__c;
     picklist=Flags__c;
     //GrantName=recordId;
    Grant=GrantName;
 
     //areDetailsVisible = false;
     areDetailsVisible = true;
 
    
    
 
     handleSuccess(){
         if(this.recordId !== null){
             this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                     title: "SUCCESS!",
                     message: "Record has been Updated.",
                    variant: "success",
                 }),  
            );
                
          }
          
          this.areDetailsVisible = false;
     }
      
     handleEdit(event){
         this.areDetailsVisible = true;
         console.log('visibleedit@@==>'+this.areDetailsVisible);
        
     }
     wiredRecord;
     parsedVar;
 
        
     @wire(getSingleSitevisit,{recrdId: '$recordId'})
     WireContactRecords({error, data}){
         if(data){
             console.log('DataTestingSiteVisit@@==>'+JSON.stringify(data));
             this.wiredRecord=JSON.stringify(data);
             let parsedVar=JSON.parse(this.wiredRecord)
             console.log('wiredRecords'+this.wiredRecord);
             this.Grant.Date_of_Visit__c=parsedVar.Date_of_Visit__c;
            this.Grant.Details__c=parsedVar.Details__c;
            this.Grant.Flags__c=parsedVar.wiredRecord.Flags__c;
             console.log('this>>'+this.Grant.Date_of_Visit__c);
             console.log('data>>'+data.Details__c);
             console.log('pars'+parsedVar.Date_of_Visit__c);
         }else{
             this.error = error;           
         }
     }
 }
```

apex class:

```apex
 public with sharing class Sitevisit{
     @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
     public static Site_Visit__c getSingleSitevisit(string recrdId) {
         System.debug('testrecordId'+recrdId);
         return [
             SELECT Id, Date_of_Visit__c,Flags__c,Details__c,Grant__c
             FROM Site_Visit__c
             WHERE Grant__c=:recrdId
             ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
             LIMIT 1
         ];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify()? That turns your object into a String value and you cannot then access properties on it - it's just a String. Date_of_Visit__c is not a property of a String, so of course it's empty.

Comment: @PapaChaos Actually I have provided it this way too without json.stringify.Mainly I used it to read the values in the console.Here I have given details field without json.stringify just data.Details__c but no value is getting entered in the related object's field.

Comment: You've got a lot more information to provide, then. What's your import statement? What does your Apex code look like? Have you done any debugging of the Apex code to make sure it is running and returning successfully? What are you doing with the error, and it does it have any contents? Oh, and since you've done the Stringify, what's the content of the String? Show more work, please.

Comment: @PapaChaos I have updated the code..Please check!

Comment: I don't see anything there that shouldn't work, but I question what you are planning to do with it. Your variable Grant is set equal to GrantName, which is the field from your Site_Visit__c object. So, Grant starts off as a map with two properties, "fieldAPIName" and "objectAPIName". You then add the properties "Date_Of_Visit__c", "Details__c", and "Flags__c" to your Grant variable - the map now has three more properties. 

What are you expecting to happen at this point?

Comment: @PapaChaos As you said the sitevisit object is a lookup field of the grant object and my first aim was to get the details entered in the component placed in the grant object get populated in the site visit object.This part is working fine.Now I have to store the details data and picklist values last obatined in the sitevisit object into the grant object for which I have queried in the apex class.While debugging the apex class the values are displayed in the debug logs but it not entering into the grant object's related fields.

Comment: Are you wanting to save data? If that's the case, I didn't understand. Nothing you have written here will write data back to the server.

You've made your Grant variable, you can also assign it an Id value:
    `this.Grant.Id = parseVar.Grant__c;`
This still won't write anything back to the server, but you can use the updateRecord method found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record to update your Grant record, if that's what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @PapaChaos So considering I add an update record method after the wire will I get the data or is it possible if I add an update method in the apex

Comment: Either way will work, but you do need to submit your data to the server. That can be done via lightning control, @wire, or explicit apex call. For what you've shown, the wired would seem to be the least onerous.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use JSON.parse()?

You need to parse this variable: this.wiredRecord

`let parsedVar = JSON.parse(this.wiredRecord)`

Then you could access the properties you need like this:

```
parsedVar.property1
```